# ion-tabs appear 1000% size

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

1. i created an app with `ng create myapp`
2. i added ionic to the project with ng add `@ionic/angular`
3. i literally copy/pasted the ion-tabs snippet from the ionic website into app.component, placed inside `<ion-content>`.
4. i ran the project with `ng serve`

And my app looks like this (this is device view in chrome btw):
[wtf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwglj.png)

(for a split second i can see the correct layout and styling then it goes to this).  WHat am i doing wrong?!?! someone PLs help

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use angular commands but looking for ionic-specific. New ionic project starts with `ionic start` and serves with `ionic serve`. Check ionic documentation.

Comment: i have used the ionic app generator and the wizard on the ionic website.  i get the same issue.  i just tried with angular cli to see if it worked but this...